# Android : Can't get bitmap from a canvas

Tags: android

I am trying to get a bitmap from a canvas by the following functionality..But I am getting the bitmap width and height -1.....Can't make out why is it happening...I have attached the code snippet below...Please help!! 
Thanks in advance :)

`private Bitmap createBitmapFromCanvas() {

```
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(panelWidth, panelHeight,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);       
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
    canvas.drawRect(new Rect(0,0, panelWidth, panelHeight), new Paint());
    for (PathListForDraw points : finalPathList) {
            canvas.drawPath(points.getmPath(), points.getmPaint());
            // canvas.save();
    }

    return bitmap;

}`
```

Comment: post the rest of your code to give more insight on the problem